# Как преобразовать дату из строки в timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть массив таких строк:
`10 янв 2016`
`04 фев 2017`
`15 апр 2017`
...
Как их преобразовать с помощью `php` в `mysql` формат `timestamp` в цикле?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью функции [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php) предварительно заменив русские слова на английские.

```
$ru_dates = [
    '10 янв 2016',
    '04 фев 2017',
    '15 апр 2017'
];

$ru_months = array( 'янв', 'фев', 'мар', 'апр', 'май', 'июн', 'июл', 'авг', 'сен', 'окт', 'ноя', 'дек' );
$en_months = array( 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' );

$timestamps = [];
foreach($ru_dates as $ru_date){
    $en_date = str_replace( $ru_months, $en_months, $ru_date );
    $timestamps[] = strtotime($en_date);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($timestamps);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если поле в MySQL имеет тип `timestamp`, то при вставке/изменении этого поля Вы используете строку. MySQL сам преобразует корректную строку в timestamp, используя для преобразования выставленную временную зону соединения (не забудьте ее установить).

Дату же к общепринятому формату можно привести с помощью функции `strptime()`, предварительно установив русскую локаль (если текущая локаль уже русская, что вполне возможно - как-то же сформировались в массиве русские названия месяцев, seltocale() можно опустить).

Код будет примерно таким

```php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1',
                   'dbuser',
                   'dbpass',
                   [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES "utf8"']);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Подключение не удалось: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit(1);
}

// Совместить текущую временную зону скрипта с временной зоной соединения с MySQL
$dbh->exec('SET time_zone = "' . date('P') . '"');

$oldLocale = setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru_RU');

foreach ($dates as $datestring) {
    $parsed = strptime($datestring, '%d %b %Y');
    $formattedDate = (1900 + $parsed["tm_year"]) . '-' .
                     (1 + $parsed["tm_mon"]) . '-' . $parsed["tm_mday"];
    $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO table (datetimefield) VALUES ('$formattedDate')");
}

setlocale(LC_TIME, $oldLocale);
```